# Google Map Geocode Not Working In Modal

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, bootstrap-modal

Google Map Geocode Functionality not working in my modal

**I tried below solluions**

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize',{});
```

BUT IT RETURNS ME Undefined Map Error

I also Tried This **[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wgur1z7n/)**

**Than i tried for**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        //My Google Map Code
});
```

But still It not Works And My Code Is as follow

```
<script>

    var map;

     function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocodeAddress(geocoder, maps);
      }

      function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
        var address = "Ahmedabad India";
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

             var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
            '<div id="siteNotice">'+
            '</div>'+
            '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Websters House</h1>'+
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
            'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
            'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
            'Heritage Site.</p>'+
            '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
            'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
            '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</div>';

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: contentString
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)',
              map: resultsMap,
              position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            //Call Listner On Click Markre
            marker.addListener('click', function() {
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }

</script>
```

And i use Following Google APi To run

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXMYKEYXXXX&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

On this line, change "maps" to "map" (the variable "maps" doesn't exist):

```
geocodeAddress(geocoder, map); // changed "maps" to "map"
```

The Geocode is working correctly for me when I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `&callback=initMap` From My API
And Add This Code

```
$("#myModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
   initMap();
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
});
```

And Its Working Smoothly :-)